# Delete the file after obtaining uri

Tags: android, file, bitmap, uri

I use the following method to get the uri from the bitmap

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    Uri storeUri = Uri.parse(path);
    File file = new File(path);
    Boolean b=file.delete();
    Log.d("DeletepathStoreUri",b.toString());
    inImage.recycle();
    return storeUri;
}
```

But this method always saves the file into the Pictures Directory and the log, always gives a false message.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> But this method always saves the file into the Pictures Directory

It will store the bytes wherever `MediaStore` wants to, in whatever format it wants, in whatever quality it wants. IMHO, nobody should be using `insertImage()`.

> and the log, always gives a false message

That is because `insertImage()` should not return a `file` `Uri` on most modern Android devices. It should return a `content` `Uri`. There is no filesystem path for you to delete.

> Where did I go wrong?

Your code, even if it "worked", would be useless. You ask `MediaStore` to write the bytes out somewhere, then you turn around and delete those bytes. This is completely pointless.

Comment: Please tell me then how else do I convert a bitmap into an URI without leaving any trace of it in the storage.

Comment: @AbhriyaRoy: If your concern is having the bitmap as a file on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), save it to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) (e.g., `getCacheDir()`), then [use `FileProvider` to serve it](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/16/how-publish-files-via-content-uri.html).